# Address to latitude and longitude - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

In my react app I need to convert street address into latitude and longitude. 
Also, it is demo project, so I am really looking for cost-free solution.

Any suggestions?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE:

I menaged to solve this problem with this package:
react-geocode

Make new project on:
https://console.developers.google.com

Enable Api:
Geocoding API

Install npm package:
npm install --save react-geocode

And follow the code instructions on:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-geocode

It turned out to be really simple stuff

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is called reverse geocoding. A quick google search brings up this library for react. It's very simple to learn and use:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-geocode

Comment: You need a service that has an index of the street names and their respective coordinates. It's not like the name of the street is encoded in the latitude and longitude. That's why you need an API like Google Maps' to get you the results. You can look for free alternatives